# d3 js tree layout multiple parents

Tags: d3.js, tree, force-layout, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to get a tree layout for a data set in which i have nodes which can have multiple parents. The links that are created in such instances have extremely large path values. is there anyway to overcome this. I can create a force layout but the tree layout feels more structured and natural to the problem in hand.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I suppose the best solution would be to write your own layout, but that would be quite a lot of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've got multiple parents, you don't really have a tree structure. A network layout is your best option. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/colin-young/5165614) is an example of a a force layout with constraints. In that case I've forced the x-values to specific values. You could do something similar using the tree level to set your x or y value.

The relevant code is:

```
var adjust_x = function(d) {
  return x(d.time);
};

force.on("tick", function () {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) {
        return adjust_x(d.source);
    }) // snipped remainder...
```